# Host a chess game locally

Tags: networking, fedora, games

I want to play chess with my friend, both of us use the [xboard](https://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/) chessboard. We don't often have access to internet connection and we want to play chess using two different computers; *the game should be hosted locally*.

Any ideas how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any alternative way to play chess using two computers?

Comment: if you are using two computers physically very close to another, you might ditch the computers and use a physical chess board instead

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann and what if we want to set far from each other and have a chess game at the same time?

Comment: Yes, there are other ways to play chess online that don't require xboard or any other local client (just a web browser).  Running your own local server is possible, but not necessary, and guiding you through that process is likely to be too broad for a single question.

Comment: We don't often have access to internet connection, that's why I want a local game.. can you please give me links instead of writing an answer, that would be great @JigglyNaga

Comment: OK, not having a constant internet collection is relevant to your question, you should [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/338043/edit) to mention that :)  I'll see what I can find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xboard has the ability to [play on a chess server](https://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/manual/html_node/Chess-Servers.html), but it doesn't provide one of its own.  To run your own local server, you will need to find some server software that implements the [Chess Engine Communication Protocol](https://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/engine-intf.html).

One currently-maintained example is called [capablanca](https://github.com/ddugovic/capablanca) - it's based on the older [chessd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/chessd/) (whose last release, described as "alpha", is timestamped 2008) and an [enhanced Lasker version](http://chess.samba.org/) (whose source links are dead).  There are detailed installation instructions in the README (too long to reproduce here).